# svn hangs during executing "svn update" or "svn checkout" command

Tags: svn, freeze

Linux host: After I execute "`svn update`" or "`svn checkout`", it hangs out, and nothing displayed, and the process is always in running status and not completed, nothing displayed on the screen.

It works fine before.

i try to use "`strace -f svn update .....`", it hangs on this step:

```
socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM|SOCK_CLOEXEC, IPPROTO_TCP) = 3
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(3690),
sin_addr=inet_addr("**.***.**.**")}, 16) = 0
setsockopt(3, SOL_SOCKET, SO_KEEPALIVE, [1], 4) = 0
read(3, "( success ( 2 2 ( ) ( edit-pipel"..., 4096) = 116
write(3, "( 2 ( edit-pipeline svndiff1 abs"..., 154) = 154
read(3, ^C <unfinished ...>
```

the svn server version on my machine:
  svn, version 1.6.11 (r934486)

The client version is:
TortoiseSVN 1.7.12, Build 24070 - 64 Bit , 2013/03/29 08:00:43
Subversion 1.7.9, 
apr 1.4.6
apr-utils 1.3.12
neon 0.29.6
OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013
zlib 1.2.7

I need to use kill command to cancel this process

I have another svn server with the same version, it works fine.

I found that a new process " svnserve -d -r repo/" will be generated after execute "svn update .." or "svn checkout".

If I tried five times, there will be five processes " svnserve -d -r repo/".

[image]

Comment: I've seen this on one machine on Win 10.  What was your resolution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is caused by permission, that the repository disk is removed from the access permission.

Answer (score 1):

You should use up-to-date Subversion. As of 2016 the only actual and supported versions are 1.8 and 1.9. SVN 1.7 and older is very old, outdated and should not be used anymore.

**Upgrade your Subversion client.**

Comment: Furthermore, SVN client is backwards-compatible with older server versions so you don't depend on some admin's will.

Comment: Hi [~bahrep], my svn server version is 1.6.11; the client version is 1.7.9.  as your suggestion, I need to upgrade my client only?

Comment: And i think this is not caused by the client version. because I have another svn server, it works fine, and the version is sample with this one.

Comment: @michelle you can upgrade TortoiseSVN only but the server upgrade is also recommended. TortoiseSVN download page: https://tortoisesvn.net/downloads.html

Answer (score 0):

In my case. When I try to update some project it would got stuck on some file. I think there are some files are corrupted because of migrating svn from corrupted hd drive to other drive.

Answer (score 0):

When I tried to run `svn update` or `svn checkout`, I encountered a similar issue that prevented me from completing the task. After some troubleshooting, I found that reinstalling SVN and deleting the configuration folder in `~/.subversion` successfully restored my ability to use the software without errors.